# ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> returns result code before returning to activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm trying to open a third party camera in my activity. It has no problem opening the camera, however, it returns the result code immediately after opening the camera and I don't know why.

Printing the result code gives '0'.

I'm wondering if there's something I did wrong here, like since my camera just takes the picture without returning anything, should written it differently?

```
private void cameraOpen() {
        Intent cam = getContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("net.sourceforge.opencamera");
        postCamera.launch(cam);
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> postCamera = registerForActivityResult( new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("SAKEGA", "WAK");
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        } else {
            Log.i("SAKEGA", String.valueOf(result.getResultCode()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: The launcher activity does not return a result. So, `registerForActivityResult()` is not useful for your `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare what should I use then?

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to accomplish. If you are trying to start the camera app, just use `startActivity()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to open the photo gallery after returning from the camera app.

Comment: How were you intending to force the user to return to your app directly from the camera app? What would stop the user from going to the camera app, then going and doing something else (e.g., via HOME navigation), and then only later trying to get back into your app?

Comment: @CommonsWare nothing. if back button is pressed and the user returns to the app then I want it to go to the photo gallery. if they leave then they leave :)

Comment: Then keep track of whether you have started the camera, and do something when you get control again in the start or resume lifecycle event.